# pl/sql developer can not display NVARCHAR2 with 64 characters

Tags: sql, oracle, nvarchar

when I update a columon(`NVARCHAR2`) in oracle database with 64 characters(0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_1) using pl/sql developer, I can update successfully.
I select this field from sqlplus:

```
SQL> select pid from pidinfo where accountid=22735;

pid

0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_1
enter code here
```

but when I use the pl/sql developer to check the result, I found that:

```
SQL> select pid from pidinfo where accountid=22735;

pid

0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_
```

you can see there is an error when pl/sql to display the NVARCHAR2 with 64 characters, pl/sql can only display 63 characters.

Is this a bug?

---

the following sql for reproduce:

```
create table PIDINFO
(
  PIDID             NUMBER(10) not null,
  PID               NVARCHAR2(64) not null,
  ACCOUNTID         NUMBER(10) default 0 not null,
);
comment on column PIDINFO.PIDID
  is 'pid id';
comment on column PIDINFO.PID
  is 'pid';
comment on column PIDINFO.ACCOUNTID
  is 'pid accountid';

insert into PIDINFO (PIDID,PID,ACCOUNTID) values (1,'wheat',22735);

update pidinfo a set a.pid='0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_1' where a.pid='wheat';
```

Comment: It cannot be..Is it showing what ever value before update. Guessing your update is uncommited

Comment: Please provide a complete example with `CREATE/INSERT/SELECT` so that we can reproduce. It's unlikely that you have found a bug. It's either a display issue (the last characters are trimmed to fit into a field) or a multi-session problem. What's the result of `select pid from pidinfo where pid='0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_1'` ?

Comment: the result of that sql is different when using pl/sql and sqlplus. when using pl/sql, the result is: SQL> select pid from pidinfo where pid='0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_1';
PID
0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_       when using sqlplus, the result is:SQL> select pid from pidinfo where pid='0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_1';
PID
0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_12111111111111112313_0005la_1

Answer (score 0):

have contract with the supporter of PL/SQL Developer, they give me the reason that "using an illegal license"